# Perfect squares formed by two perfect squares like $49$ and $169$.

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

Let $a$ be a perfect square number whose decimal representation is the concatenation of two perfect squares, for example $49$ (from $4$ and $9$), $169$ (from $16$ and $9$), ... and $4900$, $490000$ that are divisible by $10$ (simple). (What is called in mathematics such numbers?)

How we can prove there are infinitely many such perfect squares with above property that not divisible by $10$.

Comment: I might be being dumb but I am really struggling to understand what the property you want is.

Comment: I am not sure what you are exactly asking. Does the sequence $p^2$ with prime $p$ meet your requirement?

Comment: Whatever your question exactly is, the answer is probably yes and you can presumably construct such a sequence using [Euclid's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) for Pythagorean triples.

Comment: As I think @MathMan want to ask about those perfect squares which can be obtained after juxtaposition of some perfect squares. e.g. $49$ is obtained after juxtaposition of $4$ and $9$.

Comment: Now it makes sense :)

Comment: You may be looking for solutions of $a^2=b^2+10^n c^2$ for which $10^{n-1}\lt b^2\lt 10^n$ (the first part of the condition ensures that there is no single zero in the middle - double zeros can be incorporated into the first square by using $10c$ and $n-2$)

Comment: Some cases: $1681, 4225, 49729, 64009, 81225, 1024144, 225625, 2304324, 3136441, 5184729, 5929225, 15625, 42025, 93025, 819025, 1442401$

Comment: See the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which lists this as A039686 though it gives remarkably little information https://oeis.org/A039686

Comment: I asked this, which is related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937027/concatenating-squares-is-this-solution-unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$x_k = 2^{2k-1} 5^{2k} - 10^k + 1 = 4\underbrace{99...9}_{k-1}\underbrace{00...0}_{k-1}1.$$ Then $x_k^2$ has the desired property, as it is the concatenation of the squares of $$2^{k-1}5^k-1=4\underbrace{99...9}_{k-1} \quad \mbox{ and }\quad 10^k-1 = \underbrace{99...9}_{k}.$$

For small $k$, we get the following:

$$ k=1: \quad x_1^2 = 41^2 = \underbrace{16}_{4^2}\,\underbrace{81}_{9^2}. $$
$$ k=2: \quad x_2^2 = 4901^2 = \underbrace{2401}_{49^2}\,\underbrace{9801}_{99^2}. $$
$$ k=3: \quad x_3^2 = 499001^2 = \underbrace{249001}_{499^2}\,\underbrace{998001}_{999^2}. $$
$$ \vdots $$

It is an easy computation to check that this works for every $k$. Note that this method does not find *all* solutions, but it does show that there are infinitely many of them. Probably there will be other infinite families of solutions.