# Squares consisting of only square substrings.

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

The number $7^2 = 49$ is a square which has has all of it's digits being squares $2^2 = 4$ and $3^2=9$. The number $13^2 = 169$ where $4^2=16$ and $3^2=9$ can be concatenated to make $169$. So now to the question.

---

How often does this happen, that numbers which are squares have a decimal representation where the string of decimal digits is separable (not necessarily unique) into squares?

---

**Own work** So far I have mostly thought about probability and combinatorics. How many squares are in $[10^k,10^{k+1}]$ and how to combine and permute them and what distribution for digits do the squares follow.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A048375 and https://oeis.org/A198035 are relevant to your question, but these just handle concatenation into two squares, not an arbitrary number.  (Which raises the next question: are there integers that are concatenations of more than two squares?  There is at least one, $38^2 = 1444$.)

Comment: What do you mean with "how often" ?

Comment: @Peter : I was thinking something like how large percent of all squares up to $n$ as a function of $n$.

Comment: A nice example is
$$\color\green {249001} \color\red {998001}$$
Maybe, OEIS mentions it

Comment: In the case of two squares, we have to solve $$10^n\cdot a^2+b^2=c^2$$ with $b^2<10^n$. This implies $$10^n\cdot a^2=(c-b)(c+b)$$

Comment: Are leading zeros in the second block allowed ? For example : $$\color\green {1558709801289} \color\red{001}$$

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936250/perfect-squares-formed-by-two-perfect-squares-like-49-and-169?rq=1 . (I'm not voting to close because this question allows numbers that are concatenations of three or more squares.)

Comment: @Peter: Yes it is allowed since $0$ is a square of $0$ and I did not mention that the numbers must be positive or non-zero.

Comment: Are near-duplicates also being closed now? Whether there exist infinitely many is not the same question as how often. Also this question allows more than 2 squares.